# How to access multiple many to many relationships in Laravel 6/7

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Good day to all,

I have 3 models namely User, Role, and Permission.
User has a many to many relationship with Role
Role has a many to many relationship with Permission

I have 5 tables, users, role, role_user, permission, permission_role

My question is: **Is there a way in the User model to access all of the permissions assigned to the roles of the user?**

Thanks to all.

Code:
**User Model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
     public function roles()
     {
           return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
     }

     public function permissions()
     {
           //how can i get all permissions of the user
     }
}
```

**Role Model**

```
class Role extends Authenticatable
{
     public function users()
     {
           return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
     }

     public function permissions()
     {
           return $this->belongsToMany(Permission:class);
     }
}
```

**Permission Model**

```
class Permission extends Authenticatable
{
     public function roles()
     {
           return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
     }
}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer since it was incorrect. I will answer again if I can figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
     public function roles()
     {
           return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
     }

     public function permissions()
     {
           $permissionList = [];

           foreach($this->roles as $role){
               foreach($role->permissions as $permission){
                   if(!in_array($permission->name, $permissionList){
                       $permissionList[] = $permission->name
                   }
               }
           }

           return $permissionList;
     }
}
```

I think you must iterate your role first to get the permission, you can use append attribute too to get your user permission as its attribute, read more  [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json).

Oh and I remember you can use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) too so you can call your permission inside role like this `$user->with('roles.permissions')->get()` but of course you must iterate it from roles relation first to get the permissions data.

Comment: Hello sir @Adrian

The answer you gave me works beautifully.
I just removed the code:
`if ( ! in_array($permission->name, $permissionList) {
     $permissionList[] = $permission->name;
}
`
and it satisfies my requirements. Thank you for assisting me :)

and sorry for the late reply.